# fetchXML use multiple filters on a linked entity

Tags: reporting-services, filter, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

In an SSRS report I am trying to use multiply filters on a link-entity; however, it doesn't seem to be working.

Could someone look at this and tell me why it's wrong?

```
<fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical">
<entity name="jobsite" enableprefiltering="1" prefilterparametername="CRM_Filteredjobsite">
    <attribute name="jobsiteid" />
    <link-entity name="invoice" to="jobsiteid" from="jobsite" link-type="outer">
        <attribute name="jobtype" /> 
        <attribute name="service_completed_on" /> 
        <attribute name="invoicedate" />
        <attribute name="statecode" />
        <order attribute="service_completed_on" descending="true" />    
        <order attribute="invoicedate" descending="true" /> 
        <filter type="or">
              <condition attribute='statecode' operator='ne' value='Canceled'/>
              <condition attribute='jobtype' operator='ne' value='Internal'/>
        </filter>
    </link-entity>
</entity>
```

I have tried using no type, `type='and'`, `type='or'`, a filter within a filter

```
<filter>
  ...
</filter>

<filter type="or">
          <condition attribute='statecode' operator='ne' value='Canceled'/>
          <filter type="or">
                  <condition attribute='gsdac_jobtype' operator='ne' value='Internal'/>
          </filter>
</filter>
```

and varying combinations of these.

Any assistance you could offer would be most helpful, and I would be ever grateful.

Thank you,
William

EDIT: I should also say that the fetchxml works, it even filters the canceled invoices, but it seems to be ignoring the 2nd filter.

Comment: What CRM version is it ?

Comment: Sorry, the version is 2016

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `jobsite` entity, is that correct ?

Comment: yes, it is just an custom entity. also I simplified the field names to make it easier to read. I am more interested whether or not the syntax is correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

So apparently Jobtype is a calculated field, and not a simple field as I was told.

can't sort on a calculated field.... so that answers that I guess.

Thanks for your efforts.

```
    <filter type="or">
          <condition attribute='field1' operator='ne' value='somevalue'/>
          <condition attribute='field2' operator='ne' value='somevalue'/>
    </filter>
```

is the correct syntax for using multiply filters.

Comment: you mean calculated fields cant be "sort" or "filter" ?

Comment: Right, in Dynamics CRM, calculated fields cannot be sorted.